# Error H14 heroku with selenium and fastapi using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, heroku

I have a Fastapi with python that does some kind of web scraping. The api does the scraping part correctly and I'm sure of that by testing, but it shows this error when I visit the api page:

```
2022-07-08T09:15:12.564152+00:00 app[worker.1]: INFO: Started server process [4]
2022-07-08T09:15:12.564200+00:00 app[worker.1]: INFO: Waiting for application startup.
2022-07-08T09:15:12.564650+00:00 app[worker.1]: INFO: Application startup complete.
2022-07-08T09:15:12.565232+00:00 app[worker.1]: INFO: Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:47436 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2022-07-08T09:16:05.643153+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=cryptic-plateau-86689.herokuapp.com request_id=504c098c-a538-418b-898c-70ed38496780 fwd="156.146.59.25" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here's a small snippet of my script

```
dict = Scraping().get_books() # this is the web scraping part
app = FastAPI()
@ app.get("/")
def home():
      """Gets everything"""
      return dict
```

And here's my Procfile:

```
worker: uvicorn main:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=${PORT:-5000}
```

Notice that I tried using web instead of worker but I then get another error

```
 Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

Notice that `Scraping().get_books()` takes a long time (2-5 minutes) that's why I think it causes a timeout when using `web`.

Please keep in mind that I'm a beginner and here's how I think about: I think `worker` can do the web scraping part but can't handle the api part. On the other hand, `web` can handle the api part but can't do web scraping. Is this theory correct? If yes, how can I use both web and worker at the same time for different tasks?

Comment: this may not be the direct cause of your issue but beware of using the `dict` name for a variable as this will overwrite the `dict` keyword in python with your newly assigned value which may cause unforseen issues, try renaming it to something else and go from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've partly answered the question yourself: the reason you are getting the heroku error is that you are not defining a `web` process, which you [need to use to expose a web API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#the-web-process-type). You've also given the reason you're getting the other error when you *do* use the `web` process: the first line (`dict = Scraping().get_books()`) takes 2-5 minutes to run, meaning we are "stuck" waiting on the first line, so the actual FastAPI app doesn't start until after those 2-5 minutes, and heroku has a 1 minute timeout for starting the API.

Also, sidenote: `dict` is a reserved keyword in Python, so you really shouldn't use it for variable names. Try do find a more descriptive name, e.g. `book_dict`.

So what can be done to fix this? First, how often should the scraping run? Currently, you're running it once (when starting the application), and then it's fixed until you restart it. That seems a bit weird to me (as in that case, you could run the scraping part once, save that to a `json` file, and then just read that and return it). So, I'll assume you want to refresh it at least sometimes. You could run `Scraping().get_books()` inside your `home` method, but it's usually considered bad practice to have HTTP transactions longer than a couple seconds, and will often lead to timeouts.

So first, I would consider **why** the scraping job is taking so long. Are you going through a lot of pages, and if so could you split it up into a function that takes a range of pages? Or maybe, see if you can get the data directly from the underlying API instead of using selenium (see e.g. [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqtlR0y0suo)).

But if it's not possible to speed up the scraping, there are a couple of ways to deal with "long running transactions" There is no cut and dry solution to this, but I'll offer some suggestions:

1. The simplest solution might be to run the web scraping in the same process, but in a background thread:

   ```py
   import asyncio

   book_dict = {}

   async def refresh_books():
       global book_dict 
       book_dict = await asyncio.to_thread(Scraping().get_books)
   ```

   You could then run this say a couple times a day or so using the [fastapi-utils library's `@repeat_every`](https://fastapi-utils.davidmontague.xyz/user-guide/repeated-tasks/).
2. Look at a task queue library, e.g. [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html). This is a more robust way of running background tasks (but also more complex), where you'd have both a `web` and a `worker` process, with a message queue to communicate (I would suggest [RabbitMQ on heroku](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cloudamqp)). Then you'd have one API method that starts the scraping task and immediately returns the task ID, and then another method to get the task result using that ID. Here, you could also schedule that job to run a couple times per day if you wanted.

---

EDIT: You mentioned exposing a separate endpoint to scrape the data and save it to a JSON file. In this case, I would opt for using [FastAPI's built in BackgroundTask](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/), where you create a background task which runs the scraping and then saves the json file. Something along the lines of:

```py
import json

from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, FastAPI, status


def scrape_books():
    book_dict = Scraping().get_books()
    with open("books.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(book_dict, f)


@app.post("/update-data", status_code=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
def send_notification(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(scrape_books)
    return {"message": "Scraping books in the background"}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. I modified the code so that the web scraping part a json file and then the api reads it. However, I need to update this data, so I need to run web scraping when I for example visit a certain api route such as `https://{appname}.herokuapp.com/update-data`. This api route should do the web scraping part and modify the json file. I tried your first idea, but I don't exactly know how to use it. Could you explain a bit more please? Please consider that I don't need the script to be run periodically, but I need it to run when I visit a certain api route.

Comment: If you want to expose an update endpoint like that, I would opt for using [FastAPI's built in BackgroundTask](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/), where you create a background task which runs the scraping and then saves the json file. I edited my answer to include a rough example.